# Default attributes in collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My collection is `Playlist` that holds `Song` models, but I want the collection to have certain attributes like `currentSong`, `nextSong`, etc.

This is what I have right now:

```
var Playlist = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Song,

  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('playlist-backbone'),

  defaults: {
    currentSong: null,
    nextSong: null,
    prevSong: null
  },

  initialize: function() {

  setCurrentSong: function (song) {
    this.currentSong = song;
    this.trigger('currentSongChanged');
  },
```

This has led to some problems, and I wonder what might be a better way to handle this. From Backbone Github, someone suggested doing

```
var Playlist = Backbone.Model.extend({ ..  });
Playlist.songs = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ..  });
```

So I can set attributes on Playlist. Would it be the best way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to set certain attributes to any added model to your collection.

A cleaner approach would be to implement a handler for an "add" event:

```
var Playlist = Backbone.Collection.extend({
// ....
  initialize:function(){
    this.listenTo(this, "add" , this.addAttributes);
  },
  addAttributes: function(model, collection, options){
      model.set({/*...*/});
  }
```